# Как объединить элементы массива с общим ключем?

Tags: php, массивы

Реализуйте функцию, которая:

Принимает ассоциативный массив, содержащий имя владельца файла для каждого имени файла.
Возвращает ассоциативный массив, содержащий массив имен файлов для каждого имени владельца в любом порядке.
Например, для ассоциативного массива ["Input.txt" => "Randy", "Code.py" => "Stan", "Output.txt" => "Randy"] функция groupByOwners должна вернуть ["Randy" = > ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan" => ["Code.py"]].
Всю голову сломал, не могу понять элементарную вещь, как объединить два элемента массива с общим ключем

Answer (score 0):

вот так можно  объединить

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
   $res[$v][] = $k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

так чтоли?

```
<?
$array = [
  'key1' => 'val1',
  'key2' => 'val1',
  'key3' => 'val2',
  'key4' => 'val2',
  'key5' => 'val3',
];

$res = array_merge_recursive(...array_map(fn($key,$val)=>[$val=>$key],array_keys($array),$array));

print_r($res);

/** Вывод:

Array
(
    [val1] => Array
        (
            [0] => key1
            [1] => key2
        )

    [val2] => Array
        (
            [0] => key3
            [1] => key4
        )

    [val3] => key5
)
*/
```